# How does jQuery store xml used as a context parameter as it modifies it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reduce DOM manipulation during my javascript execution, and I thought about lazy-writing DOM elements, versus writing a large section of the DOM hidden and unhiding the needed parts later.

To do this, I've separated out all my DOM content into a JSP which I load into a variable via ajax and manipulate with jQuery. However, if jQuery is doing this manipulation in a hidden div on the DOM, I've achieved no performance gain. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Answer**

I just checked a couple of your [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489185/can-i-make-jquery-point-to-an-xml-document-rather-than-the-dom) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489402/manipulating-a-variable-containing-xml-with-jquery) and I think I see what you're asking here.

When you call jQuery like `$('selector string', context)` it gets routed to this:

```
jQuery(context).find('selector string')
```

do you see that? The context argument becomes the first argument to a [sub] call to `jQuery`. That in turn gets routed to this batch of shortcut code:

```
// Handle $(DOMElement)
if ( selector.nodeType ) {
    this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    this.context = selector;
    return this;
}
```

so the `context` argument gets stored on the returned `jQuery` object in the `.context` property.

Now judging from your comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489402/manipulating-a-variable-containing-xml-with-jquery/1489657#1489657), you are aware that you should have your server side code respond with a `"Content-Type: text/xml"` header. Doing so will instruct the browser to automatically create a `DOMDocument` tree from your xml response body (FYI it's accessible in the [`responseXML` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsexml-attribute) on the `XMLHttpRequest` object itself - jQuery simply passes it on to your `success` handler).

To answer your question: if you pass this `DOMDocument` object on to jQuery as the `context` parameter *and proceed to modify attributes on this object*, there is **no** manipulation in any hidden/temporary `div` that you have to worry about. The `DOMDocument` is simply mutated in-place.

Hope that answers your question.

---

**Original Answer**:

If you have html in a string and you need it to be nodes in a DOM structure, you've got to convert it somehow. Putting it inside a throwaway element is the only way I know to do this while leveraging the built-in browser parser:

```
// HTML string
var s = '<span>text</span>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
var elements = div.childNodes;
```

Many of the libraries do this more or less, including jQuery. If it makes you feel any better, the throwaway `div` above is not inserted into the DOM, thereby avoiding [DOM reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357361/how-to-freeze-web-browsers-repaints-while-changing-visibility-of-elements/1357528#1357528) (a very expensive operation), saving some cycles.

Comment: +1 - great detective work to piece together the OPs missing bits of knowledge

Comment: @Russ: thanks :) I answered a couple of the OPs questions yesterday so was familiar with his train of thought somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [document fragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) as a container to hold the generated DOM nodes.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for ( var e = 0; e < elems.length; e++ ) {
        // append elements to fragment
        fragment.appendChild( elems[e] );
}
```